# Почему атрибут id должен быть один и где ему быть

Tags: javascript, css, css3

Доброго времени суток.

Скажите почему везде говорится, что атрибут `id` в html должен быть всего **один** на странице, но у многих этот `id` стоит практически у всех тегов. И если он должен быть один то где.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: не атрибут должен быть один, а его значение должно быть уникальным на страница, об этом есть в спецификации

Comment: если будет несколько одинаковых `id` то при поиске элемента выберется только первый

Comment: @Grundy ;) вернемся к вопросу с поддеревом,  а не на странице? :D

Comment: @teran, я не помню на чем мы остановились, и на какой стороне был я :-D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`id` должен быть один. Не в смысле сам атрибут `id`, а значение его.

Если есть `input` с `id="user_email"` например, то больше такого `id` на странице быть не должно. Могут быть другие, например, `id="user_password"`, или `id="save_button"`, уникальным короче он должен быть, а не единственным. Как и любой другой `id` в любой другой системе.

Comment: давайте точную цитату спецификации тогда уж, раз про уникальность речь пошла :) хотелось бы увидеть еще толкования выражения `element home subtree`, или как оно там звучит в оригинале

Comment: @teran, плохо что поиска по комментариям нет :-) неплохо было б освежить, да и ссылки там все были :)

Comment: @Grundy  тыж программист :D https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/revision/1058514/1307147/?uid=223826&search=subtree

Comment: @teran, кстати мог бы проверить свое предположение относительно валидатора и разных веток :-) и вопрос бы отпал сам собой

Comment: @Grundy  я бы доверял валидатору от w3c, но там валидатор для html 4.01, в той спецификации судя по комментам предыдущих обсуждений уникальность была прописана на страницу целиком.

Comment: @teran, там же можно выбрать doctype html5. Сейчас проверил, на дубликат id ругается, даже если элементы с этим `id` в разных элементах лежат.

Comment: @Grundy а, точно. я только вариант с Фрагментом смотрел. он ругается на дубликат. надо написать им письмо с разъяснением :D

Comment: @Grundy все. дискуссию можно завершить :) root элемент, который я раньше считал родительским, это сам document. Так что home subtree это все дерево документа, а не от родителя и ниже. При прочтении спецификации я пропустил предлог `in`, что весьма поменяло смысл :)

Comment: @teran, собственно о чем я и говорил :-)

Answer (score 0):

```js
let s = document.getElementById("id1"); // выберется только первый

console.log(s);

let ids = document.querySelectorAll("[id ^= id_]"); // выберутся все, которые начинаются на id_

ids.forEach(function(e){
  console.log(e);
});
```

```html
<div id="id1">p1</div>
<div id="id1">p2</div>
<div id="id1">p3</div>
<div id="id1">p4</div>
<div id="id1">p5</div>

<div id="id_1">p</div>
<div id="id_2">p</div>
<div id="id_3">p</div>
<div id="id_4">p</div>
<div id="id_5">p</div>
```